# Django ORM specifc query

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 django models:

```
class TelegramUser(models.Model):
    telegram_id = models.IntegerField()
    telegram_username = models.TextField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    has_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
class DutyDate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    telegram_user = models.ForeignKey(TelegramUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    mark = models.FloatField(max_length=255, default=0)
    is_open = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I need to get all users, who has less than 3 assigned DutyDates. Can I do it with one query and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. We first count the number of related `DutyDate`s, and then we filter on that count:

```
from django.db.models import Count

TelegramUser.objects.annotate(
    nduty=Count('dutydate')
).filter(
    nduty__lt=3
)
```

Here the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) filters such that `nduty` is (strictly) less than `3`. If you want to retain `TelegramUser`s that have three related `DutyDate`s as well, you can use the [**`__lte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte).